# How to delete read and write permission file from remote server using remote server credentials

Tags: java

I need to delete read and write permission file from remote server using remote server credentials. I have coded below thing but it is not working.

```
String domain="k.com";
String userName="sampleuser";
String password="samplepassword";

UserAuthenticator auth=new StaticUserAuthenticator(domain, userName, password);
System.out.println("Auth::" + auth);
FileSystemOptions opts=new FileSystemOptions();

DefaultFileSystemConfigBuilder.getInstance().setUserAuthenticator(opts, auth);
FileObject fo=VFS.getManager().resolveFile("\\\\system\\testfile\\testfile.html",opts);

fo.delete();
```

Could you please help me for resolving this

Comment: How is it not working? Do you get an error? If so, where? Or does it not report an error, but the file is still not deleted?  etc.

Comment: File is not deleting ,It is showing error as : Caused by: org.apache.commons.vfs.FileSystemException: Could not delete "\\\\system\\testfile\\testfile.html".
 at org.apache.commons.vfs.provider.local.LocalFile.doDelete(LocalFile.java:130) ~[commons-vfs-2.0.jar:2.0-SNAPSHOT]